# ReactJS - prevent wasted render happening

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to debug simple React ToDo app. I created two components `AddTodo` (for entering input) and `TodoList` (to render todo list).

The complete code:

```
import React from 'react';

class AddTodo extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const val = event.target.elements.todo.value;
    this.props.onTodoAdd(val);
    event.target.reset();
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form action="#" method="get" autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="todo" id="newTodo" />
      </form>
    );
  }
};

const TodoList = ({ todos }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo.text}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
    };
    this.handleTodoAdd = this.handleTodoAdd.bind(this);
  }

  handleTodoAdd(todo) {
    this.setState(({ todos }) =>  ({ todos: [...todos, { text: todo, id: new Date().getTime() }]}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <AddTodo onTodoAdd={this.handleTodoAdd} />
        <TodoList todos={this.state.todos} />
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Whenever i add new todo, both `AddTodo` and `TodoList` are re-rendering (i am using React DevTools >> Highlight Updates to find which components re-rendering). But it doesn't make sense to `AddTodo` to re-render because there is no state associated inside `render` method and its un-controlled component.

Though, i added `shouldComponentUpdate`, still its re-rendering.

you can see `form` highlighted when i entered new todo in screenshot
[image]

demo available at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/725x87pk1j)

My questions are:

1. What causing `AddTodo` component to re-render when new todo added ??
2. How can i prevent re-rendering of `AddTodo` ??

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? I do see the `App` and the `ToDoList` re-rendering but not the `AddTodo`.

Comment: @Akrion I am using chrome with React Developer Tools (v3.4.2) for debugging. I am seeing form hightlighted whenever i press enter to add todo. I updated question with screenshot of hightlights

Comment: `AddTodo` isn't rerendering when we add a todo. https://codesandbox.io/s/llx3zqo489 https://imgur.com/a/yncTmhO

Comment: @HardikModha you are right, `render` method is not called when new todo added. but DevTools highlighting form element in browser. I think i need to ask seperate question what is meaning of "Highlight Updates" in React Developer Tools

Comment: What version of react-devtools and react are you using?

Comment: @HardikModha I am using React (^16.7.0-alpha.2) and React Developer Tools (v3.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

You're keep track of todos list in App component and when it re-renders, all child components will be re-rendered. To avoid this, move todos list state to inside todo list component.